# js get elements from array of a serialized form object

Tags: javascript, forms, deserialization

Im using JS for a quick web form, all is working fine, I place the responses of the form in a serialized js object into an array,

```
var myCars = new Array($('#popup-form').serialize());
console.log(myCars);
```

which gives me on the console:

```
["name=asfe&email=juan234%40gmail.com&phone=&password=&options=discuss-offer&other=", $family: Object, each: function, clean: function, associate: function, link: function…]
```

so the question is, this is not behaving like a normal array?
is the array the best way to take the elements?, I tried with mycars[0], but is not working,

Im just coming back to JS!, what is missing to get the elements for the form?, thanks!

Comment: Try `.serializeArray()`

Comment: @elclanrs thanks thats it! make it an answer to give you the vote thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery has a [serializeArray()](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) method as well.

> The .serializeArray() method creates a JavaScript array of objects,
>   ready to be encoded as a JSON string. It operates on a jQuery object
>   representing a set of form elements.